# Discrepancy of question title in Inbox

Tags: support, bug

I noticed this in a couple of places. When the OP changes the question title in between two comments, the changes are not taking effect in all places.

In my Stack Overflow profile - activity tab, the titles are in sync for all the messages in Inbox.

[image]

But in the mobile Inbox:

[image]

In the Stack Exchange Inbox:

[image]

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/